# Fastest way to check an element exists before calling a function using the elements value as parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance

I want to check if an element exists in the DOM, if it does, then call a function using the element's value as a parameter.
eg:

```
if(document.getElementById('msg')) displayMsg(document.getElementById('msg').value);
```

Is this the fastest way to achieve this?

Comment: FWIW, this is almost certainly an example of "premature micro-optimization." In general, worry about a performance problem when you have a specific performance problem to worry about.

Comment: Agreed, out of curiosity mostly. Understanding js better hopefully will help me write it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the fastest way to achieve this?

No, but it's very, very, very, very fast.

The fastest way is to remember the result of the first `getElementById` call rather than repeating it:

```
var msg = document.getElementById('msg')
if(msg) displayMsg(msg.value);
```

`getElementById` is very, very, very, very fast, and you'd have to be doing this hundreds of thousands of times — possibly millions — in a tight loop for any human to perceive the difference.

Answer (score 0):

If the id is unique enough, the element can be accessed directly from `window.msg` :

```js
window.msg && alert(msg.value)
window.msg1 && alert(msg1.value)  // window.msg1 is undefined
```

```html
<input id=msg value=hi>
```